# What does this formula (to derive annualized volatility from VaR) mean?

Tags: volatility, value-at-risk

I'm faced with the formula shown in the image below, which I just don't understand, in part because I've no grounding in stats, and in part because I don't even understand the notation:

[image]

What's going on here? Is this showing in the first line how to compute the VaR, and then in the second line how to derive the annualized volatility from some of the variables used in the first computation?

I don't even understand the "T time intervals of 1/m years" part. What's an "mth" of a year? And what does $\sigma_{\frac{1}{m}}$ mean? Is that the volatility for one time period? If so, then don't we need to aggregate the values for all the discrete time periods somehow? I'd expect to see a "sum from 1 to m" somewhere...

I'm totally confused, and any help would be very gratefully received.

Comment: looks like the EWMA/VaR model

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to calculate vola pa for SRRI.
The logic is the following:

1. If you have a VaR Limit for $1/m$ th of a year (e.g. if $m = 12$ then for one month which is  equivalent to $20$ banking days) and the risk free interest rate for a $1/m$ th of a year, this is $rf_{1/m}$ in the formula (e.g. $1$ month LIBOR), then $T=20$ and you can calculate the volatility for $20$ days, this is $\sigma_{1/m}$ ,which is implied by your VaR Limit.
2. You calculate a vola pa from it. If you calculate with $20$ days in step 1 then you have $1/m = 1/12$ and you can calculate your annual volatility by multiplying the $20$-days volatility by $\sqrt{12}$ because the year has $12$ months. Take care: this assumes uncorrelated monthly returns all having the same volatility.

EDIT: There is mix up in this answer between $T$ and $m$. Calculating the VaR with daily data we need $T=20$ and then we annualize the volatility implied by the VaR-Limit by scaling with $\sqrt{250}$.

Comment: Reading it again I see that there is a mix up. In your screenshot and in my answer. The best is if you read the correct formula in The [Esma](http://www.esma.europa.eu/system/files/10_673.pdf) publication on page 14.

Comment: In the ESMA publication above VaR is calculated using weekly data. Then $T=4$ for a monthly (e.g. $20$ days) VaR and then you see the scaling by $\sqrt{52}$ because the year has $52$ weeks-

Comment: Thanks. You're edging me towards enlightenment, but I still don't understand a couple of points: (a) If $\sigma_{\frac{1}{m}}$ is a _single_ value, then presumably the rf bit is also a single value? But the text seems to imply that it's several values: "the risk free rate **for each of the T intervals of 1/m years**"? Or am I reading that wrong, and it just means that we should use the same value for each period?

Comment: (b) if the formula only deals with single values, that makes it easier, and I can see how you can get the VaR based on the three inputs (volatility, risk-free rate and T). But how can that be solved for volatility given a particular value for VaR?

Comment: To your a) this is the risk free rate for the holding period that your VaR has. E.g. if you have the 20 days VaR then this should be your 20 days (i.e. 1 month) risk free rate - one number for this one time period. The phrase which you quote is strange ... and I find in in the ESM text too. Nevertheless I am of the opinion that this is one number on a given day.

Comment: Concerning b) Either you use a solver and solve for $\sigma$ or you use the formula for finding a root of a quadratic polynomial (in $\sigma$). You just need to find the correct coefficients and apply [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation).

Comment: I applied the formula for the quadrativ equation. It has 2 solutions but only one is positive. If I didn't make any mistake then $$\sigma = \frac{-q \sqrt{T} + \sqrt{q^2 T+2 rT^2 + 2 T VaR}}{T}, $$ where $q= 2.33$ or any other quantile, $VaR$ is clear and $r$ is the risk free rate.

Comment: This can furthermore be simplified to $$\sigma = \frac{-q+\sqrt{q^2 + 2 r T + 2 VaR}}{\sqrt{T}}. $$

Comment: @Sloucher If my answer helped you then you could mark it as accepted.